# Regex find and replace for multiple matches in a line

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex find and replace capability of my IDE to modify a piece of code I have. The code looks as follows currently:

```
//some-code
myvar = ['var1','var2','var3']
//some-more-code
myvar = ['othervar1','othervar2']
```

There are several assignment statements for the variable *myvar* as a list of strings. I want to convert those list of strings into dictionaries; with the key equal to the string, and value equal to 'my'+string. Here is how it should look like after the replacement.

```
//some-codes
myvar = {'var1':'myvar1','var2':'myvar2','var3':'myvar3']
//some-more-codes
myvar = {'othervar1':'myothervar1','othervar2':'myothervar2'}
```

I am struggling to properly match the individual strings in the list (so that I could replace them with $0:my$0). Remember, I only want to replace the list of strings that are assigned to *myvar*. All other lists of strings should be left intact. I tried using lookahead `(?=myvar =)(.*)'([a-z_]*)'`, but it matches only the last variable in the list. If I make the match lazy `(?=myvar =)(.*?)'([a-z_]*)'` , it only matches the first variable in the list.

Any help, please.

Comment: What are you trying to match? The strings within the list?

Comment: @JamesBuck Yes. Replace each string within the lists.

Comment: why don't you capture everything inside `[` and `]` and split on the basis of `,` and do whatever you want later?

Comment: @rock321987 I am looking for single line match and replace to be used with my IDE's regex find and replace. The most straight forward is to try to match a string in quote, but it will match strings at all places. Only if I could restrict it to lines begining with myvar = then it would work.

Comment: You might try [`(\bmyvar\s*=\s*\['|(?!^)\G',')([^']+)` and replace with `$1$2:my$2`](https://regex101.com/r/kM6iW9/1). Then, run the second replace: [`(\bmyvar = )\[('[^']*'(?:,'[^']+')*)]` --> `$1{$2}`](https://regex101.com/r/kM6iW9/2).

Comment: You know, you could write another program to read the source of this one line by line, and write the corrected version to another file (so that you can verify result before overwriting).

Answer (score 2):

If your IDE supports the `\G` special option you could use

```
(?<=myvar = \['|\G',')[^']+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJ2iB6/1).

Comment: problem with this is that if you update one of them all will be updated simultaneously until and unless the variable name follows some format like `var1 -> myvar1`

Comment: Thanks. It successfully matches the strings in Pycharm. But, unfortunately, when I tried to replace the matches with  `$1:my$1` it somehow messed up. Looks like it can't properly handle `\G`.

Comment: @rajendra You'll need to replace with `$0': 'my$0` since the match doesn't include the quotes and there is no capturing group 1. If that doesn't work, put brackets around the `([^']+)` and use `$1` instead.

Comment: @JamesBuck No luck with either approach. Pycharm doesn't seem to be able to handle `\G` replacements.